Bash, flatten a multilevel directrory while renaming files
I know this will sound slightly weird, but please bear with me.
My car's infotainment system seems to have a limit on how many music directories and files it will acknowledge on a USB stick:  It will randomly ignore directories or files to fit in with that limit.
My current directory structure is
Music Library
├── Artist1
│   ├── Album1
│   │   ├── Disk 1
│   │   │   ├── Track1
│   │   │   └── TrackN
│   │   │
│   │   └── Disk 2
│   │       ├── Track1
│   │       └── TrackN
│   │
│   └── Album2
│       ├── Track1
│       └── TrackN
│ 
└── Artist2
    └── Album1
        ├── Track1
        └── TrackN

etc.
I'd like to flatten the directories by copying the files to a directory called "Flat", however, there are times when the file name will be duplicated, so I'll lose some, also the infotainment system will drop any files after a certain number.
My plan was to use something along the lines of
find /Music -mindepth 2 -type f -exec cp {} /Flat/"$RANDOM"_{} ';'

The idea behind this is that by prefixing the filename with a random number, each time I run this, it will choose a different filename, allowing the infotainment system to have a different selection.
However, this tries (and fails) to create the files with slashes in them.
What can I use instead of the {} to strip the path from the destination.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this or comment to explain how this is relevant for Apple services or products? With programming problems, you want to show as much code as you can start with. Even if you have to resort to generative AI to start coding sample - show us your research and work and where you are stuck, please

Your approach would assign the same random number to each file, so it would not really help agains name clashes. I would write a small script for copying a single file, which appends i.e. $$ to the file name, if a file with the same name already exists, and invoke this script in the -exec clause (or maybe in -execdir)

You can use -execdir instead of -exec, as shown  below. The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with the exception that cp command will be executed from the directory that holds the current file.  The filename substituted for the string {} does not contain the path. (In other words, The filename substituted for the string {} is not qualified.)
find /Music -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir cp {} /Flat/"$RANDOM"_{} ';'

If you want a different random number each time a copy is made, then you may need something like the command given below.
find /Music -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir bash -c 'cp "{}" "/Flat/${RANDOM}_{}"' ';'


I don't think this works because -execdir {} doesn't propagate the path the file is in.

@JasonSalaz -execdir is executed within the path/directory the file is in, so there is no need to know it.

Ah, I was doing echo cp {} with my own tests which always printed ./file name no matter which directory it was in, and didn't consider that it's changing the working directory to the file's location when running the command.

When -execdir is used, ./file name is not printed. In other words, only the filename is printed and the ./ is not printed.

I think that stuffing everything down into a flat directory is going to cause even further issues, not to mention the insanity it will be of iterating through tracks. Surely your stereo has a concept of skipping a track, and skipping out of the current folder when you're done with it? Wouldn't randomization also render picking the song you want to find essentially impossible?
Without knowledge of your stereo, settling on a middle ground of only 1 sub-directory, maybe two, is probably (hopefully) a good enough solution.
With one directory you would probably want folders that are: Artist Name - Album Name with track names of 1-01 - Title… for multi disc albums and 01 - Title for those without. Alternatively you can just use the multi disc album version naming for everything provided that "no disc number" results in 1. (Or 0, a leading zero is fine, but a leading - probably isn't somewhere.)
This is possible but horrendously complicated to do in a script alone. There is surely software out there to help you manage this, I don't know what that software is. You have to (1) create the sub-directories, (2) copy the files to their new appropriate location in the newly created sub-directories, and (3) rename them with the disc label so that you do not intermix Disc 1 and Disc 2 and Disc n tracks that are otherwise not disambiguated.
I can get close, and it works for me because I already name my files with Discnr-Tracknr - Title formats when multiple discs are present, despite their also being organized into sub-folders:
find . -type f |awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"}{ printf "mkdir \"/Flat/%s - %s\"; cp \"%s\" \"/Flat/%s - %s/\"", $2, $3, $0, $2, $3; print ""}'
mkdir "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX"; cp "./DDR/DDRMAX/Disc 1/1-01 Lovin' You (Rob Searle club mix).m4a" "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX/"
mkdir "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX"; cp "./DDR/DDRMAX/Disc 1/1-02 Somewhere Over the Rainbow.m4a" "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX/"
mkdir "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX"; cp "./DDR/DDRMAX/Disc 2/2-01 Select.m4a" "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX/"
mkdir "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX"; cp "./DDR/DDRMAX/Disc 2/2-02 WWW.Blonde Girl (Momo mix).m4a" "/Flat/DDR - DDRMAX/"
mkdir "/Flat/Metallica - Load"; cp "./Metallica/Load/01 Ain't My Bitch.m4a" "/Flat/Metallica - Load/"
mkdir "/Flat/Metallica - Load"; cp "./Metallica/Load/02 2 X 4.m4a" "/Flat/Metallica - Load/"

Note that I took some liberties with the output like re-ordering my output to get it listed more nicely readable to prove its function.
You would then add | sh onto the end of this command in order for it to do the work running the commands listed here. This output is just printing string to verify that the commands you want it to execute would act as the way you want it to.
This solution does mean you'll get a boat load of "directory already exists" errors, but those are only a nuisance and do not stop the process.
Doable, yes. Sanely? Ehhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Mostly depends on your source file naming being rigorously exact and well organized.

Why not use the mkdir with the -p option so that "directory already exists" errors messages are not generated?

I didn't know that -p suppresses those, I only knew that switch as "make parent directory(s) if they don't exist". Looking at the man page, I see that is mentioned as part of the switch's behavior too, nice.

It's a 2024 Peugoet i-cockpit system:  When the filesystem has directories, it randomly ignores many of them.  I tried a flat system with no randomiser and it picked the first 32k files in the directory and ignored the rest, but at least I got a better selection as it was going by track name.  Once it's seen a file it sorts it by ID3 tag, so me being able to find them is no problem.
Using the randomiser is so that I can run the script again and have a different 32k files.
The system is horrible as its random play uses an 8 bit random selection, so it keeps playing the 256 tracks over & over!

It's a good thing it's a great car, because what an awful media system.
